# Corner post for flush beam deck

Tags: deck, beam

I'm replacing my deck. I would like to use a flush beam (same level as joists) at the edge opposite the ledger  because I plan to put a roof over it and I can put the roof posts right on top of the posts holding up the deck, which will be at the edge. My question is how should I handle the corner notching? Both the beam and the joists on the sides will be doubled 2x10's. If I notch the post in both directions there will be hardly any post left. See the first picture. This is what was done in the past and the beam was simple nailed to the post. I plan on bolting them, like in the second picture of a non corner post.

Old corner post:

ri[image]

A new post which is how I plan on doing it in the future:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest a 2 piece corner connector like a Simpson Strong-Tie LCE4. [Link.](http://www.strongtie.com/products/connectors/ac-ace-lpcz-lce.asp) This will transfer your load to the post below. The same connector could be used for your roof-bearing post. Or you could move the roof post in a tiny bit and use an AC connector (same link).

[image]

I'd also add some diagonal bracing from your posts for a little bit of added security.

Alternately, if you could live with the post being 3" in from the corner, you could run full length right to the roof by carriage bolting the ledgers to the outsides of the post. (This will require a bit of fiddling with the deck boards, but it strikes me as a more elegant solution.)

Comment: Thanks for the link and definitely a good idea on the diagonal bracing. I am tearing down the old deck because it was so poorly built.